# Ipad How to switch a View to a SplitViewController

Tags: ios4, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

This is what I want to do but not sure if it could be done.

my first view contains 3 buttons.
When this view is displayed, I need to present a ModalPopup for the login.
When the authenfication is done, the user can tap on one of the 3 buttons.
When the button is taped, I need to switch this view to a TabBarController and active the correct TabBarItem regarding the button.
Most of the TabBarItems can contain a SplitViewController.

I read several posts and tutorial about the SplitViewController but most of them show how to run a splitViewController from the appDelegate controller.

Then my first question would be.. is it possible :-)
The second one, would be, how?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mortoc is correct about UISplitViewController needing to be the root controller.

You can use [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad) as a drop-in replacement for UISplitViewController - and it doesn't have this limitation.

It sounds as if your hierarchy might be something like

```
UINavigationController (root)
  UIViewController (3 buttons)
  UITabBarController
    MGSplitViewController (1)
    MGSplitViewController (n)
```

Comment: Hi you all.. Thanks for your reply...
I m starting to understand how MGSPlitViewController works... Tom, do you have any example with this controller.. I m fighting to see how to integrate it from a viewController.. (I m talking about the your (MGSPlitViewController (1)). Don't know really IB and from the example with the controller it uses the MainWindow.xib... thanks anyway...

Comment: I dont have any examples.  You dont' need IB to use it - it's just a viewcontroller/view.  What is your problem, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you'll have to roll your own SplitViewController equivalent. Apple only supports UISplitViewController as the root view item: it has to be the first view loaded in your application and it's size is fixed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html